# What is the importance about sequence of declaring elements in xml

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am just learning Android programming so I decided to write a simple app about calculating BMI of people! the problem I have is that when I declare my TextView and Button first and then ImageView, all three elements fit in the screen both in portrait and landscape mode:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.bmicalculator.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BMI Calculator" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
```

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/30/4H6T2c.jpg
http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/30/3VQ0uM.jpg

But when I change the sequence and declare TextView and Button after ImageView output changes in landscape mode, TextView vanishes! Only half of Button shows and image overlays with top setting bar:

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/30/2kP5Os.jpg

But still portrait mode is OK

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/30/1l90d.jpg

So what changes when I change sequence of declaring these elements in xml? and how can I solve this. thnx

Comment: But when I declare TextView and Button first, as you see in the picture It shows all the elements and all of them fit in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.bmicalculator.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BMI Calculator"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```